# Why every time I open the IDE I have found the next error (it is something about flutter and dart config.) :

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

Error in liveTemplateContext with ID 'DART_TOPLEVEL', base liveTemplateContext is not registered plugin.xml

com.intellij.codeInsight.template.LiveTemplateContextNotFoundException: Unable to find LiveTemplateContext with class class com.jetbrains.lang.dart.ide.template.DartTemplateContextType$Generic...

For now i haven't revised this problem because i didn't make any with flutter or dart, but this problem appeared since I setting the Dart and Flutter SDKs

Comment: I have the same issue. Flutter 3.16.9, Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Flutter

Was running into a similar issue, where the IDE indexing would not complete, for both And. Studio and from VS Code.

Turns out flutter application folder was corrupt. Doing a fresh Install resolved the env. issue